# Repetition of certain words in an or statement

Tags: grammar

I have the following sentence in my thesis:

> It appears that if A is a certain language, either the converse of Proposition 1 holds or the converse of Proposition 2 holds.

I am wondering whether I can change it to the following without changing the meaning of the sentence and without violating any grammatical rules.

> It appears that if A is a certain language, either the converse of Proposition 1 or Proposition 2 holds.

English is not my native language, so if you find any other grammatical or style errors, I would greatly appreciate tips!

Comment: If the converse of the propositions is reciprocal, then it's a fine (long winded) way of writing a very simple idea. In any case it's very difficult to read and understand what you mean when the (jarring) converse is thrown into the mix. I would write it as "Either the converse of Proposition 1 or 2 appears to hold, given any certain language."

Comment: The original sentence is the one that conveys the correct meaning. I would not advise trying to shorten it. The suggested alternative is not correct. Other alternatives can be either ambiguous or convey the wrong meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [faint] chance that some readers might mis-parse OP's proposed revision as meaning *either [the converse of Proposition 1] **or** [Proposition 2] holds* (i.e. - *converse* only modifies *Proposition 1*).

I probably wouldn't bother to change the wording on that account myself - but if OP is concerned, he could always play safe and write...

> It appears that if A is a certain language, the converse of either Proposition 1 or Proposition 2 holds.

Comment: @Dimitri Surinx: I don't really have sufficient context to be sure, but on the "stylistic" front it's possible your *if A is a certain language* is a bit odd. In your context, could ***A*** be anything *other* than a language? If not, it might be better to say *It appears that **for any given language A**, the converse...*

Comment: @Dimitri: I highly recommend FumbleFingers' _play it safe_ version for two reasons. First, it's clearer than your second sentence (no ambiguity). Second, it's sound syntax because _either_ is where it's supposed to be. Most native speakers don't care about where modifiers should be in their sentences, which is one reason contemporary writing is so incredibly bad (it may not be worse than it used to be, but it's certainly no better).

Comment: There's more than a "faint chance", FF. There's a **good chance** because the sentence is inherently ambiguous. Readers will be confused by the unclear syntax, and some -- but probably not most -- will make the wrong inference. Your revision is just what's called for: clear English.

Comment: @BillFranke, I guess you ment nonnative speakers? It is not that I do not care, I just don't know where they should be. Is there any reference you can provide perhaps where I can read about such things?

Comment: @Bill: I can't accept that. We don't have the full context, but it seems almost certain to me that because of the nature of Prop1 and Prop2 (which we of course don't know), it would be obvious to the reader that only their *converses* could apply where OP references them. I do know that in any similar context relating to my own areas of technical skills, if the reader didn't already realise that both propositions needed to be reversed in such a case, he'd be too dumb to be reading my deathless prose anyway.

Comment: @Dimitri: No, I meant what I said:"native speakers of English". I've been teaching English conversation and writing to native speakers and non-native speakers for more than 40 years, and I can assure you that non-native speakers are more interested in getting everything right. Native speakers are like my teenaged son, who thinks he knows more about life than than his parents do: Native speakers think they know everything they need to know about English because it's their native language. Nonsense. Your question is a good one.

Comment: @Fu: Well, all I can say is that I stopped making such insupportable assumptions about the perspicacity of readers long ago: the best of us nod. When it's possible to easily preclude misunderstanding caused by ambiguous syntax, I think it should be done as a service to the reader. I sometimes think that you deliberately put on your ornery face because it pleases you. My cantankerousness, OTOH, is caused by pedantry, which I have previously owned up to. Pedants are like werewolves: victims of a disease who are compelled to victimize the innocent.

Comment: @Bill: Well let's not forget that you're coming at this one from the perspective of someone trying to ensure the text couldn't *possibly* be misunderstood by anyone, even if they were autistically impaired and thus unable to make logical "real-world" inferences. Dimitri here seems to have a pretty good handle on English, so I'm guessing he also knows his thesis subject inside out, and can reasonably expect his *readers* to be able to keep up without being spoon-fed the resolution to every possible ambiguity. Anyway, stylistically I *like* getting "either" in early - it's a clearer sequence.

Comment: (I admit tonight is one of my "ornery" nights. Hopefully I'll be a bit nicer tomorrow! :)